# Why am I getting a DbUpdateConcurrencyException on SaveChanges after a Rollback

Tags: asp.net-core, ef-core-3.1

My EF Core 3.1 code breaks down to the following sample. After changing some entity (MyData=1), I'm rolling back the database after an error and need to update that same entity after the Rollback (MyData=2). And, I'm getting a DbUpdateConcurrencyException on the second SaveChanges.

Why, Am I getting this exception? How can I change my code to fix the problem?

Thanks all.

```
using var MyTransaction = MyContext.Database.BeginTransaction () ;

CMyEntity  MyEntity = GetMyEntityFromDatabase () ;
MyEntity.MyData = 1 ;
MyContext.SaveChanges () ;

MyTransaction.Rollback () ;

MyEntity = GetMyEntityFromDatabase () ;
MyEntity.MyData = 2 ;
MyContext.SaveChanges () ;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because a context never resets the original values of concurrency tokens when it rereads entities.

Let's say that `MyEntity` has a `Rowversion` property as concurrency token.

The first `SaveChanges` increments `Rowversion` and EF reads the new value from the database after the update statement. This new value is stored in the change tracker as the new current value *and* original value. You can see that by checking...

```cs
MyContext.Entry(MyEntity).Property(x => x.RowVersion).OriginalValue
MyContext.Entry(MyEntity).Property(x => x.RowVersion).CurrentValue
```

You'll also see that the second `GetMyEntityFromDatabase` call won't change these cached values, even though the transaction was rolled back and the value in the database was reverted. As a matter of fact, EF isn't aware of the transaction being rolled back.

That's why you get this concurrency exception on the second `SaveChanges` call. The `UPDATE` statement contains something like `WHERE ... AND [RowVersion] = @p2;`. But `@p2` isn't the *original* original value which is still in the database.

Of course there is a simple remedy: use a new context for the second update.

Comment: Thanks Gert for your prompt response. I'm getting the context from DI. Should I simply locally create and use a new DbContext for the 2nd SaveChanges ?

Comment: Hard to tell. I don't know the reason for rolling back. If it's because some error occurred, usually the best option in such cases is to to just repeat the whole process.

Comment: This is a bummer. I'm injecting my context from DI as well and it's not so easy to create a new one. Too bad there's isn't a Reset command or something. Or some way to clear that out of the context.